# Get author username and last update username in one query

Tags: php, mysql

This question is something like a forum.
When you list the threads in a forum, usually you have to get the following:
- Subject
- Author Name
- Date of Posting
- Number of Views
- Name of Last Reply
- Date of the Above Reply

Straight enough it is.
But the problem is not about inserting the data into the database, nor updating the row.
The problem is: **LIST THE FOLLOWING** + **IN ONE QUERY**.

You may say: Hey, it is not difficult to do, you said you stored them in the database, so just fetch them. Done!
Well, if I stored the author name based on his/her name using in the time being, that might be easy. But somebody may notice your facebook friends change their **"REAL NAME"** for every 3 months. I wanted to get the latest name and then display it. So storing the name as author or last reply is not gonna work.

Some people may know how I did, and yes you got it. I stored them by their UserID. So I have 2 tables to store threads and members (actually is 3 for the contents of the threads but not important at this time). And **here is my table structure**:

```
Table: User (Part of the table)
UserID | LastName  | FirstName
-------------------------------
1      | Bill      | Gates
2      | Steve     | Jobs
3      | Chun Ying | Leung

Table: Thread (Part of the table)
ThreadID | Subject | AuthorID | LastID
---------------------------------------
1        | Hello   | 1        | 3
2        | World   | 3        | 2
```

By using PHP, I want to show all the things I mentioned at the beginning (now just forget the dates and number of views). **Like this**:

```
Subject             Author            Last Reply
------------------------------------------------------
Hello               Bill Gates        Chun Ying Leung
World               Chun Ying Leung   Steve Jobs
```

So what have I did actually? Simple, just separated into multiple queries **for each thread**. So if I have 100 threads needed to show in one page, I will have to ask my database for 401 times. That's why I am here asking for a better solutions. **I know the following code is stupid but just have a look ...**

```
SQL:
SELECT * FROM threads ORDER BY ThreadID

PHP:
while($row = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $authorLastName = $db->result("SELECT LastName FROM User WHERE UserID = '$row[authorid]'");
    // and so on ...
}
```

Well this query might be complexed but I think the solution might be useful. **Any ideas?**

Comment: Read about mysql `JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

Join the user table twice:

```
SELECT  threads.*, author.lastname, last_lastname FROM threads join user author on authorId= author.userId
join user last on LastID= last.userId
ORDER BY ThreadID
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I might just got it.
Using JOIN might be a good solution.
**(IF THE USER IS ACTIVE AND NOT DELETED BY SOMEONE)**

But I also found this way. (Using INNER JOIN)

```
SELECT t.*,
       au.lastname AS aulastname,
       au.firstname AS aufirstname,
       lr.lastname AS lrlastname,
       lr.firstname AS lrfirstname
FROM thread t, User au, User lr
WHERE t.authorid = au.userid
AND t.lastid = lr.userid
```

Hope this gonna work!

---

Now I also found another way (using LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT t.*,
       au.lastname AS aulastname,
       au.firstname AS aufirstname,
       lr.lastname AS lrlastname,
       lr.firstname AS lrfirstname
FROM thread t
LEFT JOIN User au ON t.authorid = au.userid
LEFT JOIN User lr ON t.lastid = lr.userid
```

This should solve my problem.